# Nested Flexbox height issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox, styling

Trying to get to grips with flexbox, never really used it before so apologies if I'm missing something very basic.

I have created a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jonnyfoley/pen/vxQQyN) and simplified back to basics to show my issue.

My left column will most likely contain more content than the right, but using flex box i get them to both be the same height which is fine.

The right column i would like to contain multiple sub items but would like them to fill the full height split between them which is my issue here.

I have hard-coded a couple things to make the example easier `height:400px;`

`/*uncomment this line to see desired effect*/
//height:184px;`

Comment: `.card-content,.flex-container-2 {height: 100%;}` maybe?

Comment: @AlonEitan this worked perfect, add as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inspect the elements, you see that the cars elements have 2 parents `.card-content` and `.flex-container-2` but they don't have any specific style so their height is determined only by the content inside them. In order to fix this you need to set the height to 100%:

```
.card-content,.flex-container-2 {height: 100%;}
```

This is the full working example:

```css
body {
    background: #000;
}

.card-content,.flex-container-2 {height: 100%;} /* My addition */

.flex-container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;      
}

.flex-container-2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;      
}

.flex-item {
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  padding: 0.5em;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.card-1 {
  background:grey;
  height:400px;
  width:300px;
}
.card-2 {
  width:300px;
  background:lightgrey;
}

.sub-card {
  width:100%;
  background:lightblue;
  
  /*uncomment this line to see desired effect*/
  //height:184px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="card card-1">    
      <div class="card-content">
      <h1>Title</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="card card-2">    
      <div class="card-content">
      <div class="flex-container-2">
  
          <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="card sub-card">    
              <div class="card-content">
              <h2>subtitle1</h2>
                    <p>text one</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="card sub-card">    
              <div class="card-content">
              <h2>subtitle2</h2>
                    <p>text two</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="card sub-card">    
              <div class="card-content">
              <h2>subtitle3</h2>
                    <p>text three</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        
        <div class="flex-item">
            <div class="card sub-card">    
              <div class="card-content">
              <h2>subtitle4</h2>
                    <p>text four</p>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
  
  
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the explaination